# Minishift: Failed to login to docker internal image registry

Tags: docker, openshift, docker-registry, minishift

I have been using the mini-shift for local testing.

I was trying to push the docker images to the image registry of Minishift.

## Failed Info:

[image: failed to login to the registry].

Comment: it is showing incorrect username and password are you sure your username and passwords are rights.

Comment: I was using the user:`system`, password:`admin` or token those are default details of `Minishift`

Comment: The Minishift registry login procedure is described in details [here](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/openshift/openshift-docker-registry.html), make sure not to skip [step 2](https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/using/docker-daemon.html). I.e. run the `eval $(minishift docker-env)` command and check that you're not attempting to connect to the cluster's internal registry service IP within the `172.30.0.0/16` range (used for service IP's that are not externally available).